# App crashes on ios 4.X for framework Twitter.framework

Tags: iphone, ios4, twitter, ios5, sharekit

I am using twitter using Sharekit and for IOS5, I am using its class `TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass`   as,

```
Class TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass = NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController");

    if (TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass != nil) {
        if([TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass respondsToSelector:@selector(canSendTweet)]) {
            UIViewController *twitterViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass alloc] init];

            [twitterViewController performSelector:@selector(setInitialText:) 
                                        withObject:NSLocalizedString(@"TwitterMessage", @"")];



            [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:twitterViewController animated:YES];
            [twitterViewController release];
        }
    } else {
        [SHK flushOfflineQueue];
        SHKItem *item = [SHKItem text:text];
        //[SHKTwitter shareItem:item];
        SHKActionSheet *actionsheet = [SHKActionSheet actionSheetForItem:item];
        [actionsheet showFromToolbar:self.navigationController.toolbar];
    }
```

It is working fine with simulator 5.0 but crashes on 4.3 with below error.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/Twitter.framework/Twitter
      Referenced from: /Users/indianic/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.3.2/Applications/241167D0-62E0-4475-85FD-0B8253B4E456/demoFBTW.app/demoFBTW
      Reason: image not found
```

How do I fix this.
I tried to change the dependency for the framework from *Required to Optional* but didn't find for that

Comment: Twitter.framework only possess support in ios 5 not in ios4

Comment: So i wont be able to use `TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass` for app which is using both ios5 and ios4? Because I am using sharekit for <ios5

Comment: "...but didn't find for that". What do you mean by "didn't find for that"? Do you mean you couldn't find the option in Xcode?

Comment: yes i didn't find dependency option for framework

Comment: I am finding for weak linking

Comment: I got it.To use `weak linking` we need to make framework from Required to Option and that is from BuildPhases->LinkBinaryWithLibraries->make it optional

Comment: Yep, that's it. I suggested a bug fix and a little simpler code in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you found how to weak link the framework. Assuming you are using Xcode 4.2 and LLVM3, you can also simplify this code a bit and fix a bug you have while you're at it:

```
#include <Twitter/Twitter.h>

// This line is no longer needed:
// Class TWTweetComposeViewControllerClass = NSClassFromString(@"TWTweetComposeViewController");


// this part can now be:
if ([TWTweetComposeViewController class] != nil) { // no need to look up class by string now

    // note previously you were checking if this class responds to 'canSendTweet'
    // but you never called the method to see if you can actually send the tweet

    if([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]) {

        // you can type this correctly now...
        TWTweetComposeViewController *twitterViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

        // ... and call this method directly
        [twitterViewController setInitialText:NSLocalizedString(@"TwitterMessage", @"")]; 

        [self presentModalViewController:twitterViewController animated:YES];

        [twitterViewController release];
    }
}
... continue with the shareKit option
```